# How to visit vagrant machine using spacemacs?

Tags: spacemacs

I want using my emacs with spacemacs config to connect vagrant and to some python develop,how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

For vanilla Emacs, you can use tramp-mode to connect to the Vagrant machines via SSH using C-x C-f. I think the same key binding will work on Spacemacs too.

But Spacemacs being Spacemacs, you can check out this layer, which provides the feature you want: https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/tree/master/layers/%2Btools/vagrant

Note that it also uses tramp-mode under the bonnet!

Comment: My vagrant layer has benn installed and when I type SPC V t It can not list the vagrant VMs on my laptop ,what's wrong with it,could you give some example that include details, thanks a lot!